# Using different div tags in one line

Tags: css, html

I would like to have colored vbars between my links. What is the best way to do that?

**The case**

```
Home | About us | Contact
```

The vertical bars need to be blue. When I use a `<div>` tag with color blue I get this:

```
Home 
|
About us
|
Contact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to `float:left` is to use `display: inline`, that can cause other unexpected behaviors but it might work for what you need. Also, you can you a `<span>` which is the same as a `<div>` except it is `display: inline` by default

Answer (score 6):

Use a list, with `a` elements:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about.html">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then use CSS to style those elements:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    border-left: 2px solid #00f;
    margin: 0;
}

ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 0 none transparent;
}

ul li a:link,
ul li a:visited {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em; /* or whatever */
}

ul li a:hover,
ul li a:active,
ul li a:focus {
    color: #f00;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LGdkE/).

Answer (score 1):

`div` elements are block-level elements, which means that they are formatted visually as blocks (e.g. paragraphs). You could use a `span` instead, since `span` elements are inline-level elements which do not form new blocks of content.

However, your markup would be more semantic if you just give the `a` elements right borders (except the last one).

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">Home</a><a href="#">About us</a><a href="#">Contact</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a { border-right: 1px solid red; }
a:last-child { border-right: none; }
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9frds/) fiddle for a live demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can float your items to the left.

Answer (score 0):

you need top float the divs to the left

```
div{
   float:left;
}
```

edit:
you should give them a class

```
.navDivs{
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: If he adds this in his css stylesheet, the page will probably look funny :p

Comment: probably so, had he asked the question properly and included code, i could have been more specific

Answer (score 0):

You can use `span`:

```
<span style="color: blue;">|</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
            #menu a {display:inline-block;border-right:1px solid blue;padding:5px;color:blue;text-decoration:none;}
            #menu a:hover {color:red;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='menu'>
            <a href='/home/'>Home</a>
            <a href='/about/'>About Us</a>
            <a href='/contact/'>Contact</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Fiddle Live Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/StefanCoetzee/KKSBJ/).

Comment: Also use #menu a:last-child {border-right:none;} as suggested by melhosseiny (as shown in my fiddle).

Comment: This answer is also semantic and requires much less css and less html than David Thomas's answer.  But if you insist on using list elements you can just change the menu div here to a menu ul and wrap the anchors in li tags.